# UiTabbar Icon doesn't display correctly

Tags: iphone, icons, uitabbar

I am trying to upgrade my app to display icons that look great on the retina screen of the iPhone 5. AS of right now I am not setting my icons using code, I'm simply selecting the image within xcode and it loads it on its own ( I don't know how to code in the icon so that's why I am doing it this way).

Anyways, when I set the icon I have to use a 24x24 icon or else it wont fit. 
When I use my high-res icons 64x64 they do not fit correctly. My question is, how do I go about making it so my icons will be scaled to fit but still retain the high-res quality?

Answer (score 0):

1) If your non-retina icon is 24x24, then your retina icon should be 48x48

2) You should set your icon to be the non-retina version in interface builder. The retina version will be swapped out automatically if its on a retina device, as long as you follow the standard naming scheme:

```
name.png     (non-retina image)
name@2x.png  (retina image)
```

Note also: if you do set an image in code, you can simply use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever"]` and the retina image will be swapped out automatically for you too (you don't have to do if-else or anything like that).

Comment: I can only set one image in the interface builder so how could I go about doing that? The 48x48 doesn't fit either. I'm asking, if there a way for it to make it resize to fit? Similar to how the icons and loading screens work.

Comment: Just set the non-retina icon in interface builder. An icon sized at 24x24 should fit on UITabBar.

Comment: I understand that, that's what I have been doing. I'm saying it looks like crap so I HAVE to use a higher quality.larger image. When I do that they do not fit. So, again, I am asking is there a way to set it to do something similar to scale to fit, just like the loading screens and app icon.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a "scale to fit" option for images set on `UITabBarItem`s. You have to design them at the correct size (I believe the max size is something like 42x42 for non-retina... see this other SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803836/how-to-scale-a-tabbaritem-image ). Personally, I find that 30x30 non-retina images work really well.

Comment: You can try dropping the image into PhotoShop and just resizing it, but this may not turn out great (depends on complexity of the image). For complex images, I've actually designed them at a pixel by pixel level, which is kind of a pain, but it turns out the best that way in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

just try to set this code in your `.m` file of your particular tabBar's parent view.. in `viewDidLoad:` method..

```
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home@2x.png"];/// set your image name instead of home
```