# UITabBarController functionality with UITabBar

Tags: ios5, xamarin.ios, interface-builder, uitabbar

I'm making an app with interface builder using storyboarding.

I want to have a tab bar where no item is selected. This can be accomplished by setting

```
TabBar.SelectedItem = null;
```

But if you try to do that, you get the following error:

```
'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'
```

So I can't use the standard `UITabBarController`. I've created a custom `UIViewController`, and added a `UITabBar`.  Switching between tabs is working fine, and having no selection is also working as it should.

But I have no idea how to show my other view controllers from my custom view controller with the tab bar. Remember that I'm using interfacebuilder, so I can't just create my view controllers in code as new objects and add them to the view. *(as suggested in [UITabBar funcionality without UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308458/uitabbar-funcionality-without-uitabbarcontroller))*

So how do I show my own views without using the UITabBarViewController?

---

Edit: Still haven't found a solution, but I did a hacky fix. Simple create an other tab bar and place it on top of the original tab bar. Listen to those events and use `SelectedIndex` to change the view displayed. Then add some function that will select / deselect the items on your own tab bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, even if you design your others `UIViewControllers` from IB, you can instantiate them from code. You'll probably have to play a bit with frame and autoresizing properties to make them fit the part of your main view you want them to display inside, but it's possible.

So, knowing that, a simple solution is to create a simple `UIView` (we'll call it 'tabFrame') in your main `UIViewController`, which fill the screen from the top of your `UITabBar` to the top of the screen; instantiate the `UIViewController` corresponding to your tabs and add their view as subview of `tabFrame`. Now you just have to catch item selection from tabbar to hide or show the desired subviews.

Hope I'm clear enough, else don't hesitate to question!

**EDIT**: pointed out this morning that in storyboarding context, you can effectively instantiate viewControllers / scene from code, but for not loosing designer settings it must **NOT** be done through directly calling their constructors, but through `StoryBoard.InstantiateViewController("vc_identifier")` calls, after having set identifiers to VCs in storyboard editor.

See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/recipes/General/Storyboard/Storyboard_a_TableView for example

Comment: yeah I thought of that, but we're not talking about IB's here. I'm using storyboarding.

Comment: oh yeah, I was thinking of XIB's :P anyway, I know I can instantiate them from code, but they loose some of the settings I've made in the IB

Comment: I've never been confronted to this problem (loosing IB settings when instanciating from code) and didn't even knew about this possibility, so sorry for the wrong solution and good luck!

Comment: maybe I'm just doing it wrong, but try making a grouped UITableViewController in IB, the default constructor is YourClass(IntPtr handle) : base (handle){} . how would you create an instance with that contructor?

Comment: I have no Mac at home so can't verify or test until tomorrow, but from my memory I believe I had just created another constructor wich didn't need this `IntPtr handle` thing.

Comment: yes, you can just create your own constructors, but then you need to call the correct base constructor that gives you the correct layout. If you just do a YourClass():base(){} you will lose some settings. But it might just be caused by a misunderstanding of the IntPtr. Maybe it's good enough to call base(UITableViewStyle.Grouped). I haven't tested this good enough yet. See http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewController%2fC.

Comment: Ow, bad point for me, I read `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`. I'll test some things tomorrow, too many interesting questions to keep theorizing!

Comment: tested this again, and my original theory was correct. When you make your own constructor the things you've made in IB are not loaded. Seems like you earlier could load your NIB/XIB with this mehtod http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=C%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController%28System.String%2cMonoTouch.Foundation.NSBundle%29 but I don't see this working for storyboards.

Comment: Have you seen the edit I did this morning? Don't know if OP get notifications when an answer is edited?

Comment: don't think so. This would be the correct solution! Thanks for all the help. Thought I saw something like that a few weeks ago, but completely forgot about it.