# TabBar without TabBar Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am writing an iPhone app which is like a 5-6 level down DrillDown app. I am almost done writing my app, and now a new requirement has come up to add a TabBar (Navigation Bar in JQuery) from the 3rd screen onwards.

I am using UINavigationController for all my scenes in the app.

I have written all the scenes in my app. Here is what my storyboard looks like:

[image: StoryBoard]

Now, for I need the tab bar for my 3rd level of uinavigation (as in the storyboard). If I simply embed these views in a Tab Bar, will it start working?

Note: View 2 has buttons, which if pressed take to different views and I need these same buttons in the tab bar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use tabbar without tabBarController also, you just need to add views in it instead of viewcontrollers. And that would get mannaged automatically.

Comment: Alright. Could you give me some reference links or something? I am very new to this, so don't really know how to achieve that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308458/uitabbar-funcionality-without-uitabbarcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Yu can make your own tab bar object and connect it to a tab bar delegate. At delegate object you have to have method:

```
– tabBar:didSelectItem:  required method
```

After you've done this, you have your own tab bar with your own behaviours. You can connect it to navigation controllers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a tab bar or would a tool bar do the same job?

THe tabBar is usually a top level component, and each tab then has its own UINavigationController and view controller stack.

As you said that you need this on the 3rd level, this to me sounds like a good use of the toll bar, with subviews inside that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ToolBar seems to fulfill my purpose. I have a number of button and they are not coming up in the available space. Can I add multiple rows of buttons? Or have a scroll button which shows more buttons when pressed?

Comment: That does not really look too neat.

Comment: Then you may need to create a custom component with the layout and style you need.